# How to properly monitor and log Android OS events/activity in the background

Tags: android, events, operating-system, monitor, polling

I would like to know the correct way to monitor system events and operating system activity in Android.  My research so far indicates there are various methods for running Activities, Services, BroadCastReceivers, etc. but I don't have an overall comprehensive answer for everything I want to accomplish yet.  I did come across an app today called "Carrier IQ" and was wondering how they do it.  I believe their app is built into the kernel or at least the phone's OS image, something I want to avoid doing if at all possible.

I know that the Android SDK offers various ways to obtain 
Since my app cannot be allowed to be suspended, should it run as a foreground service?  If I do this, will I consume too many resources if I need to poll for various activity?  I ask this because I don't think I can get everything through receiving events (i.e., using a BroadCastReceiver).  I think I need a combination of polling and events.

I want to log sensors, events, OS activity, etc. for a user study.  This is NOT for hacking or phishing purposes!

These are the top three projects that I think may accomplish something similar to what I want to achieve, but I have not yet determined if they are viable solutions:

[android-hci-extractor](https://code.google.com/p/android-hci-extractor/)

[cellbots data logger](https://code.google.com/p/cellbots/source/browse/trunk/android/java/dataLogger/#dataLogger/src/com/cellbots/logger)

[android-os-monitor](https://code.google.com/p/android-os-monitor/)

Comment: "I would like to know the correct way to monitor system events and operating system activity in Android" -- out of ~8 billion people on the planet, zero know what you mean by "system events and operating system activity". Please provide a **complete and specific** list of **everything** you wish to collect, as there are likely different approaches and APIs for each.

Comment: There is the rub.  I'm supposed to start out with a basic framework that will allow future "plug-ins" to support new things that should be monitored.  I know it's very vague, which is part of the problem.  But to start out with I need to monitor sensors, operating system functions (CPU usage, network usage, etc.), and user activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare another thing:  This is mostly a background process that will log to a file, so a UI like most OS monitors have for end-user viewing is not necessary.  All of the logged data needs to be saved out to a file for transfer to a backend server that with perform the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Android manifest permissions list contain all of the permissions your app will need?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Then you can just ask for permissions when the app is installed and you should be able to access them.

Comment: At this point I am not concerned with permissions.  Assuming the app has permissions to access what is needed, I need to know the best way to construct the overall framework so that polling is kept to a minimum and the app doesn't get suspended while working.  I'm basically trying to avoid creating an Android "antipattern."